# asp.net button in ITemplate doesn't fire Repeater ItemCommand event

Tags: asp.net, button, repeater, itemcommand, itemplate

i am a complete asp.net noob and the solution could be something very simple.

i have found, read and tried many answers to questions very similar to my question, but nothing works. i hope to find some help here.

**this works perfectly with no problem:**

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" onitemcommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text='<%# (Container.DataItem as Choice).description %>' CommandName="Choice" CommandArgument='<%# (Container.DataItem as Choice).id %>'/>
            <br />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

code behind:

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        List<Choice> choiceList = new List<Choice>();
        // ... code to fill the list ...
        Repeater1.DataSource = choiceList;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
}
void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int idx = int.Parse( e.CommandArgument.ToString() );
    // this function is called
}
```

**but if i use ITemplate it doesn't work:**

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" onitemcommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
    </asp:Repeater>
```

code behind:

```
public class MyButtonTemplate : System.Web.UI.ITemplate
{
    public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
    {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.CommandName = "choice";
        button.DataBinding += new EventHandler(Button_DataBinding);
        container.Controls.Add(button);
        container.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
    }
}
static void Button_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    RepeaterItem repeaterItem = (RepeaterItem)button.NamingContainer;
    button.ID = "button" + (repeaterItem.DataItem as Choice).id.ToString();
    button.CommandArgument = (repeaterItem.DataItem as Choice).id.ToString();
    button.Text = (repeaterItem.DataItem as Choice).description;
}
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        List<Choice> choiceList = new List<Choice>();
        // ... code to fill the list ...
        Repeater1.ItemTemplate = new MyButtonTemplate();
        Repeater1.DataSource = choiceList;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
}
void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int idx = int.Parse( e.CommandArgument.ToString() );
    // this function is NOT called
}
```

the buttons are displayed, but the event is not fired.

i have already tried saving a delegate in MyButtonTemplate and assigning the button click event - it does not work.

thank you!

Comment: Try to remove the `if (!Page.IsPostBack) {` check in the `Page_Load`. Since is not present in the page, you need to bind it every time the page is loaded....

Comment: @JinJi I am facing the same problem do you had a solution to this?

Comment: @SanjuRao the first comment from SmartDev is the solution :)

Comment: @JinJi yeah got it. thank u very much.  :). but in my case InstantiateIn method dose not fire :(